# INSERT INTO tbl ON DUUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - a blank row gets inserted?

Tags: php, mysqli

What is wrong with this MySQLi statment?

I want to do an INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

schema

```
'UID', 'char(17)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'stationID', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'temperature', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'UV', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'temperature_feels', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'humidity', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'weather_type', 'int(11)', 'YES', '', '-1', ''
'precipitation', 'float', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'update_station_id', 'tinyint(4)', 'YES', '', '1', ''
'update_due', 'timestamp', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'weather_status', 'varchar(128)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

// code

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO weather_data (uv, weather_status, weather_type, temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation, UID)
            VALUES (uv, weather_status, weather_type, temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation, UID)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uv = ?, weather_status = ?, weather_type = ?, temperature = ?, temperature_feels = ?, humidity = ?, precipitation = ?, UID = ?";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new \Exception($dbh->error);
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $uv, $weather_status, $weather_type, $temperature, $temperature_feels, $humidity, $precipitation, $UID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

It seems to insert an empty row every time?

Comment: Before write insert set an select. If ***count is zero*** then **insert** else do **update**

Comment: @Abdulla - that's exactly opposite of what should be done and the OP is trying to do it right. Please don't suggest incorrect solutions.

Comment: I need to do this via a insert into on duplicate key update - although that would have been my first method too

Comment: @Zabs - you're doing it right. Performing `SELECT` first and then `INSERT` leaves you open to concurrency problems and you can get duplicate records (at best, it's also slower to do select first followed by insert). Do you have a unique key set? If yes, which column? What is a blank row? Everything goes blank or only certain columns? You checked whether your variables are not empty?

Comment: I have the UID as my primary key, for some reason a row is inserted with all empty values for each column??

Comment: Where are you setting/binding the insert values? I only see the update values being set/bound.

Comment: Where are parameters for the insert values? You just repeated column names there..

Comment: how do i amend this to do an insert or update if the UID (PK) already exists?

Comment: You have to change `VALUES (uv, weather_status, weather_type, temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation, UID)
` into `VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` first. Your actual insert part is wrong completely, you're not inserting any values from variables, you're inserting basically nothing. I wonder how come MySQL didn't complain about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks kind of crazy but the initial values for all the fields are strings ( of sorts ) and not placeholders. You would need to bind for each

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO weather_data (uv, weather_status, weather_type, temperature, temperature_feels, humidity, precipitation, UID)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uv = ?, weather_status = ?, weather_type = ?, temperature = ?, temperature_feels = ?, humidity = ?, precipitation = ?, UID = ?";

    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssss', $uv, $weather_status, $weather_type, $temperature,
                           $temperature_feels, $humidity, $precipitation, $UID, 
                           $uv, $weather_status, $weather_type, $temperature, 
                           $temperature_feels, $humidity, $precipitation, $UID);
```

Comment: Instead of binding everything twice, you should be able to use `uv = VALUES(uv), weather_status = VALUES(weather_status)` etc in the `UPDATE` part

Comment: I don't know about that - seems feasible though so +1

Answer (score 1):

Update your query to:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  uv = VALUES(?),
  weather_status = VALUES(?),
  weather_type = VALUES(?),
  temperature = VALUES(?),
  temperature_feels = VALUES(?),
  humidity = VALUES(?),
  precipitation = VALUES(?),
  UID = VALUES(?)
```

Also the issue is that param go's with each `?`, since after the insert you continue to use `?` you need to add those arguments as well. You could avoid this with PDO using named params.

```
$stmt->bind_param('dsidddddidsidddddi', /* first set dsidddddi */ 
  $uv, 
  $weather_status,
  $weather_type,
  $temperature,
  $temperature_feels,
  $humidity,
  $precipitation,
  $UID,
  $uv, // because ? counts further.
  $weather_status,
  $weather_type,
  $temperature,
  $temperature_feels,
  $humidity,
  $precipitation,
  $UID,
);

$stmt->execute();
```